# Replace NaN values in pandas dataframe with a computation from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with column3 containing NaN values. I want to replace these NaN values with column2-column1. But column 2 is a string and I want to take the first four digits from the string and convert it to integer before subracting.

I tried this:

```
df.column3.fillna(int(df.column2[:4]) - df.column1)
```

And I get this following error:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str[:4]` for first 4 values of strings with convert to numeric by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df.column3 = df.column3.fillna(df.column2.str[:4].astype(int) - df.column1)
```

Or by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) if first solution failed:

```
df.column3 = df.column3.fillna(pd.to_numeric(df.column2.str[:4], errors='coerce') - df.column1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.column3.fillna(df.column2.str[:4].astype('int') - df.column1)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!